# How to delete files from SVN that have already been deleted from the FS?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Using TortoiseSVN on Windows, how do I delete files from the repository that have already been deleted on the file system? I would expect them to show up as "missing" or "deleted" on my next commit, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

On Linux/Mac, I just run this command:

```
svn st | grep ^! | cut -b7- | xargs svn delete
```

-Chris

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to use "Tortoise svn -> delete" to delete the file.

If you have deleted directly by mistake, do an svn update to get the file back and then do "tortoise svn->delete"

:-)

Answer (score 3):

Right click and open the TortoiseSVN repository browser.  You will see the file in the repo and can delete it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Files show up as "missing" in the commit dialog of TortoiseSVN only if the folder where they were deleted in is versioned and still present. If you deleted the whole folder, it won't show up as missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted the file by accident (without using svn) you can simply revert that modification to get the file back, then delete it with svn. Or install the svn command line in parallel and use that for deletion :)

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can even select 'svn delete' from the context-menu on the revert dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on windows, and use svn from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

on linux, also considering files with white spaces:

```
svn st | grep ^! | cut -b9- | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' | xargs svn rm
```

this works on windows as well if you install git for windows (msys), or cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted the file before it was committed for the first time, you cannot revert from the repository and then get the files back to Tortise svn > delete as suggested by Indhu.

I just ran into that case where I used Tortise svn -> Add on a few files, and then deleted the files directly before I had committed.  Probably an uncommon case, but here is how I fixed my problem:

First, I created new (empty) files with the same file names as the now "missing" files.  Then, I then did a Tortise svn > Undo Add on each file.  This caused svn to stop trying to commit files with those names.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with deleting files after 'adding' but before 'committing'

I fixed this when doing a commit, by right clicking on the files that didn't exist and selecting 'delete' from that menu. Then commit.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a dead thread, but I had the same problem.  I 'added' files, then deleted them before I 'committed'.  Because of this, the SVN revert would not work.

I fixed this by right clicking on the directory the files where in, and doing an SVN-> check for modifications.  The modifications brought up a dialog that allowed me to select the files that were missing and delete them from the repository.

Hope this helps someone and saves them some time.